# Shutter animation messed up when adding UIImagePickerController as subview

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm adding `UIImagePickerController` as a subview of my `UINavigationController` which is inside a `UIPopoverController`.

Heres the code:

```
        UIViewController *container = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        self.navigationBarHidden = YES;

        camera = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        camera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [container addChildViewController:camera];
        [container.view setFrame:camera.view.frame];
        [container.view addSubview:camera.view];

        [self pushViewController:container animated:YES];
```

Everything looks great but the shutter animation. It seems to be off center, where the middle of the iris is actually hitting the top of the view.

How do I fix the shutter animation?

Comment: did you find an answer yet? I have the same issue...

Comment: Not yet. If you find a solution let me know.

Comment: Yes I will let you know, if I got the solution. Temporarily http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098236/iphone-how-to-stop-shutter-animation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010602/hide-shutter-in-uiimagepickercontroller could be helpful